# convert string into seconds using ctime

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a function that converts a string in the format H:MM:S into seconds using time.ctime( and convert it back to clock. How can I do this in python?

For example:

"123:00" would produce an output of 7380

"0:01" would produce an output of 1

"0:00:00" would produce an output of 0

i have started with this code

```
def convert_to_seconds(time_as_a_string):
    time = []
    start = 0
    seconds = time.ctime(seconds)
    if seconds >0:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `ctime()`:

```
def to_secs(time):
    time = [int(i) for i in time.split(':')][::-1]
    return sum(time[i]*(60**i) for i in range(len(time)))

def to_clock(secs):
    time = ['']*3
    for i in range(2, -1, -1):
        time[i] = str(int(secs/(60**i))).zfill(2)
        secs %= 60**i
    return ':'.join(time[::-1])

assert(to_secs('123:0') == 7380)
assert(to_clock(1) == '00:00:01')
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using Ctime:

There's always the unnecessary hard way that's pretty trivial to read/understand.

```
def safecast(newtype, value, default=None):
    try:
        return newtype(value)
    except ValueError:
        return default

def theHardWay(timestring):
    count = timestring.count(':')
    if type(timestring) is not str or count > 2:
        return 0
    if count == 0:
        return safecast(int, timestring)
    timelist = timestring.split(":")
    if len(timelist) == 2:
        return safecast(int, timelist[0], 0) * 60 + safecast(int, timelist[1], 0)
    if len(timelist) == 3:
        return safecast(int, timelist[0], 0) * 3600 + safecast(int, timelist[1], 0) * 60 + safecast(int, timelist[2], 0)
    return 0 # should never be touched

assert(theHardWay("123:00") == 7380)
assert(theHardWay("123:ThisShouldNotFail") == 7380)
assert(theHardWay("000:00:1") == 1)
assert(theHardWay("0:00:000") == 0)
```

And then there's a much, much easier way:

```
def theEasyWay(timestring):
     return sum([safecast(int, n, 0) * 60**i for i, n in enumerate(timestring.split(":")[::-1])])

assert(theEasyWay("123:00") == 7380)
assert(theEasyWay("123:ThisShouldNotFail") == 7380)
assert(theEasyWay("000:00:1") == 1)
assert(theEasyWay("0:00:000") == 0)
```